# I cannot understand how Prolog knows what the start state is in a DFA accept rule

Tags: prolog, dfa

I worded the title the best way I could think of, but let me make it clear.  When programming a DFA in Prolog, here is a typical manner of doing so:

```
start(q0).
final(q2).

transition(q0, a, q1).
transition(q1, b, q1).
transition(q1, c, q2).

accept(Symbols) :- start(StartState), accept(Symbols, StartState).

accept([], State) :- final(State).

accept([Symbol|Symbols], State) :- transition(State, Symbol, NextState), 
                                accept(Symbols, NextState).
```

I understand what this code does, what its goal is, and all that.  What boggles my mind are the "accept" rules.  Again, I understand the logic behind what is being performed, but what I do not understand is the sudden usage of StartState and NextState.  These just come out of nowhere, and I don't understand how start(StartState) would even return true to begin with, much less where the value comes from.  The same with using NextState.  What values does Prolog "think" is in these and how are they accepted by the transition facts?

If I start with the fact: start(q0)., then how is start(StartState). true?

Comment: @CapelliC I think OP meant they understood the *intention* of it, what it's *supposed* to do. English is a fickle language, it can be parsed in so many subtly different ways.

Comment: Yes, of course that's what I meant. Thank you @WillNess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While mat's answer is correct, I'll give you here a bit of operational semantics, i.e. *how* does it happen.

You ask, *"If I start with the fact: `start(q0).`, then how is `start(StartState).` true?"*

Answer: `StartState` is a *logical variable*. It doesn't have any value set to it yet. It is we that write this name, "out of nowhere" - it could be any name we choose; Prolog sees it, sees it's a new name (starting with an upper case letter), and creates a new logvar with that name, which is not yet *instantiated* (assigned a value). It's like a NULL pointer, which can be set *only once* at a later point (unless the system backtracks, but that's an orthogonal issue).

This is how Prolog works: it sees a query, `start(X)`; it sees `X` is a new logvar; now it tries to *prove* this query. That means, it searches among all known facts and rules for such with *head* that *matches* our query.

There is one: it's the fact `start(q0)`. Note `q0` starts with a lower case letter. This means it's an *atom*, a symbolic datum. Variables start with upper case letters.

How does Prolog find the fact `start(q0)`? It just does. That's a detail of a given Prolog implementation. It finds it among all the facts and rules that constitute the program that we wrote, and loaded into Prolog.

Now the system matches `start(q0)` with `start(X)`. This is called *unification*:

```
start(q0) = start(X)
```

this succeeds, with `X = q0`. A logvar `X` gets assigned its value, and the match succeeds. Thus the query is proven, with the *substitution* `{ X = q0 }`.

This is how Prolog works.

But really, you should read a good Prolog tutorial, so that you understand all *italicized* words in the above. There will be even more issues to learn after that, so you could eventually be confident that you "understand" Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's really the most trivial and basic thing: Given a fact

```
start(q0).
```

The query:

```
?- start(State).
```

succeeds *and* yields `State = q0`, which can be obviously deduced from the given fact, since this is exactly what the fact says: `start(S)` is `true` **if** `S = q0`.

Read your clauses declaratively, for example: **If** `start(State)` holds *and* `Symbols` are accepted starting from `State`, **then** `accept(Symbols)` holds. Try to read the other clauses in the same way, and it will become clear what they say.